# How to integrate Attention mechanism to training process with Sentence Transformers?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I am trying to apply attention mechanism to my training process. Below you can check it.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer, InputExample, losses
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader

class CosineSimilarityAttention(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CosineSimilarityAttention, self).__init__()

    def forward(self, sentence_embeddings, domain_embedding):
        # Normalize the embeddings for cosine similarity
        norm_sentence_embeddings = F.normalize(sentence_embeddings, p=2, dim=1)
        norm_domain_embedding = F.normalize(domain_embedding, p=2, dim=1)

        # Compute the cosine similarity
        attention_scores = torch.matmul(norm_sentence_embeddings, norm_domain_embedding.unsqueeze(-1))

        # Squeeze to remove the last dimension and apply softmax
        attention_scores = attention_scores.squeeze(-1)
        attention_weights = F.softmax(attention_scores, dim=1)
        return attention_weights

class CustomSentenceTransformer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, sentence_model):
        super(CustomSentenceTransformer, self).__init__()
        self.sentence_model = sentence_model
        self.attention_layer = CosineSimilarityAttention()

    def forward(self, input_embeddings, domain_embedding):
        # Apply the attention mechanism
        attention_weights = self.attention_layer(input_embeddings, domain_embedding)
    
        # Ensure attention weights are properly aligned with input_embeddings for broadcasting
        attention_weights = attention_weights.unsqueeze(-1)
    
        # Multiply each embedding by its corresponding attention weight
        weighted = attention_weights * input_embeddings
    
        # Sum across the sentence dimension (assuming dim 1 is the sentence dimension)
        weighted_embeddings = weighted.sum(dim=1)
        return weighted_embeddings
```

```
# Function to separate utterances to use them in Attention mechanism
def split_into_utterances(text, separator="<SEP>"):
    return [utt.strip() for utt in text.split(separator) if utt.strip()]
```

```
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer, InputExample, losses
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
import torch

# Convert triplets to InputExample format
examples = [InputExample(texts=[anchor, positive, negative]) for anchor, positive, negative in triplets]

model = SentenceTransformer('all-MiniLM-L6-v2')

# Define the Loss Function
train_loss = losses.TripletLoss(model=model, distance_metric=losses.TripletDistanceMetric.COSINE, triplet_margin=0.25)

# Training
train_dataloader = DataLoader(examples, shuffle=True, batch_size=16)

model.fit(train_objectives=[(train_dataloader, train_loss)], epochs=4, warmup_steps=100) #, output_path = "domain_recognition_model")

# Save the model
#model.save('domain_recognition_model')

# Save the model's state dictionary
torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'domain_recognition_model_state_dict.pt')
```

My data already has been divided into triplets (anchor, positive, negative). I can train the data with couple lines of code from Sentence Transformers as I have shared here. The point is I want to apply additional Attention mechanism to improve my training process. Because the anchor is dialogue context, I want the model to understand domain (positive) anchor relationship better, for that I want to divide dialogue context into sentences and get final embedding as weighted sum of all these sentence embeddings which will cause the sentence with higher proximity to domain label has higher influence on final embedding.

How can I train my data with Sentence Transformers by integrating this attention mechanism?